# Why is the year returned wrong for this code?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I wrote this script just for practice and for some reason there is an issue with the year returned after the customer enters their year of birth. For example, my friend was born in 1991 but in October. The code works fine for January but for October, it states that the NYE of that year (1991) was in 1992 for my friend's birthday (which is October 13th, 1991). Please advice!

I tried reading manual for year but not much offered. I googled, but this question is very vague.

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

today = date.today() # date.var returns date
print '\nToday is', (today.strftime('%B')), (today.strftime('%d')), (today.strftime('%Y')) # time formats used to return mo, day, yr

print "\nHello! What is your name?"
user_name = raw_input('--> ')
print '\nHow old are you, %s?' % user_name
user_age = int(raw_input('--> '))

# Python lists start with 0 index so add in a dummy for 0
months = ['Dummy', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
print '\nWhat day, month and year were you born?'
user_day = int(raw_input('Day: ')) # use this line to get index from months list
user_month = months.index(raw_input('Month: '))
user_year = int(raw_input('Year: ')) 
date_birth = user_year, user_month, user_day

print '\nYou were born on', date_birth

NYE_birth = (today.year - user_age, 1, 1)
print 'The New Year\'s Eve of that year was ', NYE_birth
print 'You were born', user_month - 1, 'months and', user_day - 1, 'days after NYE.\n'

# need to include months

ry = 100 - user_age
age_cent = date (int(today.year + ry), int(user_month), int(user_day))
print '\nWow, a long way to go! You will turn 100 years-old on',  age_cent
print '\n'
```

The expected outcome should be that NYE is the same year as user's year of birth. But it shows the following year.

Comment: Can yyou show an example output?

Comment: Your NYE calculation doesn't even take the date of birth into account, it simply subtracts the age from the current year.

Comment: I suggest you take another look at `today.year - user_age` and consider cases when they have not had their birthday this year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your friend was born in October, 1991, he's still only 27 years old now, he'll be 28 after his next birthday. When you subtract 27 from the current year, it's 1992.

If the birthday is later in the year than when you run the program, you need to subtract an additional year to account for this.

```
if today.month > user_month or (today.month == user_month and today.day >= user_day):
    NYE_birth = (today.year - user_age, 1, 1)
else:
    NYE_birth = (today.year - user_age - 1, 1, 1)
```

You'll need to make a similar adjustment for the century year.

Of course, since you ask what year they were born, you could just `user_year` instead of calculating it from the age.

Comment: thank you brother! It worked. I took a little while to answer because I wanted to test it out before I reply. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC try using:

```
from datetime import date, time, datetime, timedelta

today = date.today() # date.var returns date
print '\nToday is', (today.strftime('%B')), (today.strftime('%d')), (today.strftime('%Y')) # time formats used to return mo, day, yr

print "\nHello! What is your name?"
user_name = raw_input('--> ')
print '\nHow old are you, %s?' % user_name
user_age = int(raw_input('--> '))

# Python lists start with 0 index so add in a dummy for 0
months = ['Dummy', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
print '\nWhat day, month and year were you born?'
user_day = int(raw_input('Day: ')) # use this line to get index from months list
user_month = months.index(raw_input('Month: '))
user_year = int(raw_input('Year: ')) 
date_birth = user_year, user_month, user_day



print '\nYou were born on', date_birth


NYE_birth = (user_year, 1, 1)
print 'The New Year\'s Eve of that year was ', NYE_birth
print 'You were born', user_month, 'months and', user_day, 'days after NYE.\n'

# need to include months

ry = 100 - user_age
age_cent = date (int(today.year + ry), int(user_month), int(user_day))
print '\nWow, a long way to go! You will turn 100 years-old on',  age_cent
print '\n'
```

Comment: the line about the stats of the user's birth is innacurate since it states that user was born 10 months after NYE, which would be November. :(